# Download a File using MIDP 1.0

Tags: java-me

I have a J2ME app using midp 1.0 and i want to download a file much like I would using midp 2.0 platformRequest().

What do i do?

Michael

Answer (score 0):

Sorry nothing, midp1 doesn't support platform request.

And any of the other workarounds like file access wont be supported on MIDP1 either.